# Set transcriptional temaplate for SMTP emails in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

I want to send email using SMTP in Magento2 I tried following code

```
 public function execute()
{

      $smtpHost = '***.*****.***';
      $to = 'email.com' ? 'email.com' : 'test';
    $smtpConf = array(
        'auth' => 'login',
        'port' => '25',
        'ssl' => 'tls', 
        'username' => 'email.com',
        'password' => '123456'
    );
    $transport = new \Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($smtpHost, $smtpConf);
    $from = trim('email@gmai;l.com');
    $mail = new \Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom($from, 'test');
    $mail->addTo($to, $to);
    $mail->setSubject('Hello from MagePal');
    $mail->setBodyText('Thank you for choosing MagePal extension.');
    $result = __('Sent... Please check your email') . ' ' . $to;
    try {
        //only way to prevent zend from giving a error
        if (!$mail->send($transport) instanceof \Zend_Mail){echo $result;}
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      echo   $result = __($e->getMessage());
    } 

  }
```

And its working but I want to call transcriptional template how I can call? I have create 1 email template in admin with id 2.

Please let me know how I can call transcriptional email template of SMTP emails.

Answer (score 0):

`\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` is what you need here.

So add a constructor to your class where you inject your dependency:

```
  private $_transportBuilder;

  public function __construct( 

   \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder

  ){
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
  }
```

And then don't use Zend_Mail, generate your template in a separate method:

```
public function generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
{
    $template =  $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->temp_id)
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, /* here you can defile area and
                                                                             store of template for which you prepare it */
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
            ->setFrom($senderInfo)
            ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']);
    return $this;        
}
```

and call it in your execute method:

```
$this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);
```

Comment: Hi It is not working for me:(  Can you please explain me how I can send it with SMTP class object?